# Importing from `index.js` results in "Target container is not a DOM element." error within Jest/RTL tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I've configured React Router in `index.js` as follows...

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import ErrorPage from "./components/ErrorPage/ErrorPage";
import store from "./store";

// https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

In `setupTests.js`, I'm using a custom `renderWithProviders()` function to wrap around React testing Library's render function, as described in https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#custom-render:

```
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

// import { router } from "../index";  // This is causing the test error
import { server } from "./mocks/server";
import { setupStore } from "../store";

// Establish API mocking before all tests
beforeAll(() => server.listen());

// Reset any request handlers after each test
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());

// Clean up after all tests are finished
afterAll(() => server.close());

export function renderWithProviders(
  ui,
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    // Automatically create a store instance if no store was passed in
    store = setupStore(preloadedState),
    useRouter = false,
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return useRouter ?
    (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterProvider router={router}>
          {children}
        </RouterProvider>
      </Provider>
    ) : <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
  }

  // Return an object with the store and all of React Testing Library's query functions
  return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) };
}
```

And finally, I have the following in `App.test.js`:

```
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { screen } from "@testing-library/react";

import App from "./App";
import { renderWithProviders } from "./testSetup/setupTests";
// import { router } from "./index";  // Breaking tests here too

test('App dummy content is rendered', () => {
  renderWithProviders(<App />);  // Breaking despite not using the router
  expect(screen.getByText("Hello World!")).toBeInTheDocument();
});

// This is what I wanted to test using the index.js router config
// test('An invalid path returns an error page', () => {
//   renderWithProviders(
//     <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/invalid-path"]}>
//       <App />
//     </MemoryRouter>
//   );
//   expect(screen.getByText("Sorry, an unexpected error has occurred!")).toBeInTheDocument();
// });
```

This all works fine without importing `router` from index.js, and has done since before I started trying to configure React Router within my test setup.

```
PASS src/App.test.js
  √ App dummy content is rendered (47 ms)
```

However, as soon as I uncomment the router import in either `setupTests.js` or in `App.test.js`...

```
import { router } from "../index";
```

...I receive the following error when running `npm test`:

```
FAIL src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

      18 | ]);
      19 |
    > 20 | const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
         |                       ^
      21 | root.render(
      22 |   <React.StrictMode>
      23 |     <Provider store={store}>

      at createRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:29345:11)
      at Object.createRoot$1 [as createRoot] (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:29800:10)
      at Object.createRoot (node_modules/react-dom/client.js:12:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.js:20:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:6:1)
```

If I re-comment the import(s), the test works again.

The strange thing is, the import isn't even being referenced in `App.test.js`; just importing it causes the issue.

I also tried renaming the router variable and associated imports to `appRouter` in case there was a name collission, but that didn't change anything.

I also tried importing my own constant from `index.js`, which resulted in the same error, so it seems to be the nature of importing from that file (possibly before the route is rendered) which is the issue.

```
export const categoryListings = categories.map(category => {
  return {
    path: "categories/" + category.path,
    element: <PostListing name={category.name} />,
  }
});
```

The entire respository is here if that's useful: https://github.com/Cmastris/redducational/

Anyone have any ideas what's going on, and preferably how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You likely want to be using a `MemoryRouter` in your unit tests since the test environment isn't a browser DOM environment. Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] so it's clear exactly what is declared and/or imported/exported from/to?

Comment: Thanks! For context, I looked at using `MemoryRouter` but I wanted to test serving of the error page and any future configs in my production `createBrowserRouter()`, which is why I was trying to import it. However, on reflection, that probably isn't necessary as long as it follows the documentation. Sure, I'll add the imports/exports to the code snippets.

Comment: I updated the post and also made a note about trying to rename the variable (it didn't change the behaviour).

Comment: Sorry, was out yesterday and caught up in meetings today. Looks like you arrived at the solution I was suggesting. Glad it's working for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pleased to report that I managed to get this working, although I'm still not sure precisely what the original issue was. Sharing my solution for anyone else who has a similar issue...

I noticed that importing another constant from `index.js` resulted in the same error, so it seems to be the nature of exporting/importing from `index.js` (possibly related to exporting/importing before the route is rendered) which is causing the issue.

I moved all of my routing config to `routing.js`...

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import { categories } from "./data/categories";

import App from "./App/App";
import ErrorPage from "./components/ErrorPage/ErrorPage";
import PostListing from "./features/postListings/PostListing";


export const categoryListingRoutes = categories.map(category => {
  return {
    path: "categories/" + category.path,
    element: <PostListing name={category.name} />,
  }
});

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        element: <PostListing name="All" />,
      },
      ...categoryListingRoutes
    ],
  },
]);
```

...leaving just the `RouterProvider` in `index.js`...

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

import { router } from "./routing";
import store from "./store";

import "./index.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Then, based on [@Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)'s suggestion to use `MemoryRouter`, I used `createMemoryRouter()` together with my categories routing config to test the routing. No import-related errors this time, and the test is passing:

```
test('Category listing routing', () => {
  const router = createMemoryRouter(categoryListingRoutes, {
    initialEntries: ["/categories/science"]
  });

  renderWithProviders(<RouterProvider router={router} />);
  expect(screen.getByText("Science")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```